# How can I know if an SQLexception was thrown because of foreign key violation?

Tags: c#, .net, sql, sql-server, validation

I want to tell the user that a record was not deleted because it has child data, but how can I be sure that the exception was thrown because of a foreign key violation? I see that there a sqlexception class that is used for all sql exception.

Answer (score 50, accepted):

Assume you're using SQL Server.

Using teh web archive - https://web.archive.org/web/20190120182351/https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/tomholl/2007/08/01/mapping-sql-server-errors-to-net-exceptions-the-fun-way/

```
try
{
    # SQL Stuff
}
catch (SqlException ex)
{
    if (ex.Errors.Count > 0) // Assume the interesting stuff is in the first error
    {
        switch (ex.Errors[0].Number)
        {
            case 547: // Foreign Key violation
                throw new InvalidOperationException("Some helpful description", ex);
                break;
            case 2601: // Primary key violation
                throw new DuplicateRecordException("Some other helpful description", ex);
                break;
            default:
                throw new DataAccessException(ex);
        }
    }

}
```

Case 547 is your man.

**UPDATE** The above is sample code and should not be used. Please follow the link as to explain why.

Comment: If you follow the link, and read down, you'll notice that the code above is given as an example of how *not* to do it...

Comment: Absolutely correct - I had only intended to have this code here to show an expanded version of the error catching. I suppose I should put a notice not to use (since that's the issue with the other page).

Comment: @aronchick why do you set the if condition `if (ex.Errors.Count > 0)` ? why it is useful ?

Comment: Just to see if there's any errors (there could be more than one).

Comment: Why so many thumbs up if this is apparently an example of how NOT to do it ??

Comment: Because it shows how to unpack the errors in C#. The link shows how to do it in SQL server, which was not the original question. There's nothing significantly wrong with the code, the author just doesn't like this pattern.

Answer (score -3):

You can write your exception-expected code in the Try block if any exception will be thrown it will be catch further now you can get error number.now can check is it a **Foreign Key violation** or not

```
try
 {

//your deletetion code

 }catch (SqlException ex)
    {

        if (ex.Errors.Count > 0) // Assume the interesting stuff is in the first error
        {
            switch (ex.Errors[0].Number)
            {
                case 547: // Foreign Key violation
                    lblError.Text = "Cannot Delete this Record this is associated with other record...!";

                    break;
                default:
                  throw;

            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Please do not repeat other answers