# Which Error Code is return in SQL Server when inserting duplicate value in primary key column (table)

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005, ado.net

Which Error Code is return in SQL Server when inserting duplicate value in primary key column (table)

```
  try
     {
         dataAdapterObj = new  SqlDataAdapter(selectString, conObj);
         return true;
     }
     catch (Exception e)
     {
         MessageBox.Show("Exception is : " + e.ToString());
         return false;
     }
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2403348/how-can-i-know-if-an-sqlexception-was-thrown-because-of-foreign-key-violation

Comment: Easy enough to test isn't it?

Answer (score 6):

The error code is 2627 (Violation of PRIMARY KEY constraint)

```
  try
     {
      // do insert
     }
  catch (SqlException e)
    {
       if (e.Number == 2627)
           //do something
    }
```

Comment: For anyone looking over this in the future. a 2627 is VERY different from a 2601. A 2601 is a unique key violation A 2627 is a primary key violation. Which means, if you are like me you use Identity values for the majority of your PRIMARY KEYS. Meaning you should never get a 2627.

Answer (score 4):

The error code you're looking for is 2601.  Use the [SqlException.Number](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlexception.number.aspx) property

```
catch (SqlException e)
{
   MessageBox.Show(String.Format("Exception is {0} - {1}", e.Number, e.Message)); 
}
```

Comment: It's not a method, it's a property available to the SqlException object thrown when a sql exception occurs.

Comment: This Code is Every time same or different ?

Comment: @ChrisGessler In my project SQL server will return 2627 when duplicate value in primary key violate 2601 and 2627 at same time. Since you said 2601 would be the error code when duplicate value in primary key, I asked for help [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/57197737/7786739). I think 2627 would be more proper error code the OP were seeking. What do you say?

Answer (score 3):

**2601**

Example: Cannot insert duplicate key row in object 'my_table_name' with **unique index** 'my_index_name'.

**2627**

Example: Violation of `PRIMARY KEY` **constraint** 'my_constraint_name'. Cannot insert duplicate key in object 'my_table_name'.

Source: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/sql/sql-server-2008-r2/cc645728(v=sql.105)