# Difference between "Cannot insert duplicate key row in object" vs "Violation of UNIQUE KEY constraint"

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, sql-server-2008

Is it the same sql exception when we get "Violation of UNIQUE KEY constraint 'XXXXXXX'" vs "Cannot insert duplicate key row in object 'dbo.XXXXXX' with unique index 'XXXXXXX'". 
In my serverside code we used to handle this with like following:

```
catch (SqlException sqlEx)
{
  if (sqlEx.Message.Contains("Violation of UNIQUE KEY constraint 'XXXXX'"))
  {
    .....
  }
}
```

But now the sql server is not prompting the error "Violation of UNIQUE KEY constraint 'XXXXX'", instead it's just saying "Cannot insert duplicate key row in object 'dbo.XXXX' with unique index 'XXXXXX'."

Is there a way in the configuration of MSSQL that I get a descriptive sql exception and get the text "Violation of UNIQUE KEY constraint" back?

Comment: Yes - it logically is the same issue. No - there is no switch that will force the engine to return the same message for the two similar (but not exactly the same) situations.

Comment: @SMor "(but not exactly the same) situations" can you elaborate, please?

Comment: The object it is complaining about... is it a unique _constraint_ or unique _index_?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why does violation of PRIMARY KEY constraint return error code 2627 not 2601 in SQL Server?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57197737/why-does-violation-of-primary-key-constraint-return-error-code-2627-not-2601-in)

Comment: A unique constraint @SalmanA

Comment: @Jackboys are you sure it is a constraint and not an index?

Comment: @SalmanA I belive its both.

Comment: Do a `EXEC sp_help tablename` and note down the list of indexes and constraints. I believe you're using an index instead of constraint. Ideally you should check for both cases as suggested in the answer below (and use error number instead of string match... imagine a SQL server using french locale), but you could also replace the unqie index with a unique constraint. They are same.

Answer (score 2):

The first error happens when you attempt to insert a row that violates a unique constraint on a table.
The second error happens when the row violates a unique index.
It's a subtle difference and frankly, I don't really know why there are two different errors for that, especially considering that a unique constraint is implemented in SQL Server using a unique index.

Anyway, I wouldn't use the error message as an indication of what error you've got. Instead, I would check the error number, exposed in the SqlException class as an int property named - surprise surprise - [Number](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.sqlclient.sqlexception.number?view=netframework-4.8#System_Data_SqlClient_SqlException_Number).

You can get a list of all error messages and their relevant numbers by querying `sys.messages`. 
I've done this with a like predicate on text to get the relevant errors for your question:

```sql
SELECT message_id, [Text]
FROM sys.messages 
WHERE [Text] LIKE '%Cannot insert duplicate key%'
```

Which returned:

```
message_id  Text
2601        Cannot insert duplicate key row in object '%.*ls' with unique index '%.*ls'. The duplicate key value is %ls.
2627        Violation of %ls constraint '%.*ls'. Cannot insert duplicate key in object '%.*ls'. The duplicate key value is %ls.
```

(And thanks to Larnu's dupe suggestion, I found the link for [Database Engine Errors](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/errors-events/database-engine-events-and-errors?view=sql-server-2017), but It's faster to query the database than to load that page...)

So, change your c# code in the `catch` block to

```cs
// Cannot insert duplicate key..., Violation of UNIQUE KEY...
if (new int[] {2601, 2627}.Contains(sqlEx.Number))
{
  ....
}
```