# Detecting foreign key conflicts

Tags: c#, sql-server

Sometimes when you try to delete a row in a table in SQL server you get an error since that row acts as a foreign key in another table.

How do i detect this in Visual studio 2013 when i execute a delete command in my form

Comment: Please show some code, but I would venture try{}catch{} aqnd catching the appropriate SQL exception

Comment: @3dd this would be better if the OP would have their checks done in a `Stored Procedure or Query` checking the `sys.foreign_keys` if it exist then can't delete if it does not exist..then move forward with the delete.

Comment: The correct way to handle this would be....know your data, know the data you are coding with. Your application should know which data depends on each other, and delete everything according to the rules implied by data.
What are you going to do if a foreign key constraint forbid you to delete data? you should answer this question before trying to work around it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I didn't knew what exception to catch by i guess i didn't google hard enough

[How can I know if an SQLexception was thrown because of foreign key violation?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2403348/how-can-i-know-if-an-sqlexception-was-thrown-because-of-foreign-key-violation)

Answer (score 0):

Can you not just perform and or execute a query / stored procedure to check the following

```
IF NOT EXISTS ( SELECT  name
     FROM    sys.foreign_keys
     WHERE   name = 'FK_Name' ) 

//do some work or your Deleting etc...
```

Comment: The presence of a foreign key constraint does not indicate that a delete will fail.  It might indicate that there is the possibility it will fail, but not whether it will or not.